# Move the join button to somewhat up as its touching the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code for a sample welcome page for an app. I  tried doing all methods in the alignment class. If possible give a solution related to changes in the alignment class. Also if improvement is needed in any part of the code, feel free to correct me.I wrote this in Dart language using Flutter SDK in VS Code

```
import 'package: flutter/material.dart';

   class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
     const LoginPage({super.key});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Stack(
 children: [
  Container(
 decoration:  BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
   image: const DecorationImage(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/8.png"))
  ),
  ),

  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottom,
    child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
        );
      
    }, 
    
    child: const Text("JOIN NOW",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0 ,color: Color.fromARGB(255, 251, 250, 249))
    ),
    
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 10, 9, 9),
       // padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 15),

        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only( 
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                //topRight: Radius.elliptical(10, 40),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                

               // bottomRight: Radius.elliptical(10, 4)

                

                //  bottomLeft:, bottom left
                // bottomRight: bottom right
            )
          )
    ),
  ),
  )  

 ],

);
}
 }
   class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
const SecondRoute({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Login Page'),
  ),
);
}
}
```

[Here is the output in chrome web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V5Ez.png)

I tried doing all methods in the alignment class. If possible give a solution related to changes in the alignment class. Also if improvement is needed in any part of the code, feel free to correct me. I wrote this in Dart language using Flutter SDK in VS Code